# Modify dependency files using prepare_command

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a Pod that depends on `Mantle`. I want to use `prepare_command` in my podspec to modify a `Mantle` file. But, it seems like the command runs before the `Mantle` dependency is downloaded during `pod install`. Is there a way to modify the dependency files from within my podspec?

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: Yes. But, only if you host your own private podspec like this: https://github.com/magnetsystems/Specs/blob/master/Mantle/3.0.0/Mantle.podspec.json#L21